Math_Physics - Regarding Conservation Laws
If the time variance of a conserved quantity in a (source-less/sink-less) system is given by the flux integral of the flow field over the boundary, we should have:
$$\partial_t q(t) = \int_{\partial U}\langle X,n\rangle dA.$$
If $n$ is taken to be an outward pointing, unit-normal field, an incoming flux would yield a negative inner product and so putting a negative outside this expression on the RHS would cancel out. However, if we take inward pointing field, incoming flux would be positive and we don't need the negative outside.
When we try to apply general divergence theorem to get the differential formulation of conservation laws, we reach a point where that negative is vital and there is no reference to the normal field. The proof of the general divergence theorem, which uses general Stokes' theorem doesn't make use of the orientation choice (see Ch.16 in Lee's Smooth Manifolds around pg.411 and pg.422).
The argument looks like this:
Provided $q(t) = \int_Uu(x,t)dV$ and $U$ $\color{blue}{\text{is a compact, oriented,}}$ $\color{blue}{\text{[simply connected] Riemannian manifold with boundary, $X$ is smooth, and $n$ is unit normal}}$, we have using the first equation:
$$\partial_t \int_UudV = \int_{\partial U}\langle X,n\rangle dA = \int_U div(X)dV$$
$$\implies \int_U(\partial_tu(x,t) - div(X(x,t)))dV = 0.$$
Now if we find $u$ making the integrand vanish, the integral will vanish and hence the original equation will be satisfied. So we would be justified in calling:
$$\partial_t u = div(X)$$
the differential formulation of conservation laws. However, as can be seen on wiki and in Evan's Partial Differential Equations (p.610), there is a sign discrepancy from this result.
Maybe this is a solution verification, I'm looking to justify I guess the negative in the very beginning.

$\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$ Divergence measures the tendency of a flow field to leave a point. So a field with positive divergence about a single point within a volume should be more aligned with the outward surface normal. Negative divergence can be thought of as positive convergence.
$\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$ With that in mind, the density for a quantity associated to the field should increase within a container if there is flow coming in to it. So positive increase in density over time corresponds with positive convergence (negative divergence) of the flow. Same goes for the negation. This suggests:
$$\partial_t u(x,t)\sim -div(X(x,t))\text{ }\text{ }\text{ (within the volume $``U$")}.$$
We could take this to be equality or otherwise if we suspect direct proportionality, leave it up to a constant, or even some polynomial form to be experimentally determined. Since we can arrive at such a desired form starting with the flux integral stated in the question, we don't have to work too hard. Just take the outward normal definition with the negative.
$\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$ There is the nuance that the flux integral was supposed to be for a field with no sources or sinks in the interior of the volume. In this case the divergence will be zero throughout and the field lines will necessarily continue on through the other end of the volume's surface, leaving the density unaffected (after an initial wave passes through the whole volume). Thus the equality will still hold (both being zero).
$\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$ When the contribution from the field's sources/sinks in the interior of the volume are not negligible, the flux equation in the beginning of the question will have an added term that propagates through the analysis. >>

'Time direction' is a critical point in first order evolution equations. The two signs make a difference between time forward and backward equations.
Generally a vector field $X$ is the non-exact local generalization of a gradient field $X\ = \ \nabla \rho$ and if the quantity $\rho $ is conserved over all of volume in time forward, for a gradient field we will have
$$\partial_t \rho = \Delta \rho = \nabla \cdot \nabla \rho $$
such that by Stokes
$$\partial_t \ \int_V \rho dV \  = \  \int_{\partial V} dV'(\nabla \rho)$$
with the conventions, that the surface $(n-1)$ form of a ball $dV'$ lost its radial 1-form $\text{dr}\wedge dV'$ on the left and the differential volume as a surface volume layer $\partial V$ means the difference between a ball f radius $r+dr$ minus that at $r$.
With these conventions, set by the definition of divergence
$$\nabla \cdot X =\lim_{V\to 0} \ \frac{1}{|V|} \int_{\partial V} dV'(X) $$
and the subtleties of the antisymmetry of $n$-forms, the right side is a negative operator in
$$\int f \partial_t \ \rho \ dV = \int f \ \nabla \cdot X dV = - \int\ \nabla f  \cdot X \ dV $$ for any $f$ with compact support away from the boundaries. From these considerations its clear, that $\Delta =\nabla\cdot \nabla$ is  a negative operator and a gradient field pointing outward yields a flow with decreasing substance in the volume.
As abstract as the differential topology and the wave- and diffusion equations of mathematical phyisc, so easy are the basics to be understood in a 2d space-time.
If one starts with a concentration of a swarm of independent particles in the origin, the diffusion equation has the solution of a broadening Gauss distribution $$\left(\partial _t - \partial_x^2 \right) \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} \ e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 t}}\  = \ 0.$$  No possibility to solve for negative times.
If one reverses $\partial_t \to -\partial_t$, obviously it's possible to calculate the solution as start distribtion above at $t>0$ backward in time until for $t\ge 0$, where its becoming singular.
Since the equation is linear, any positive start distribution $\rho_0(x)$ at $t=0$ folded with with the Gauss kernel is a solution
$$\left( \partial_t-\partial_x^2\right)\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} \ e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{2 t}} \rho_0(\xi) \ d \xi \ =\ 0$$
This trivially says that any small intervall evolves it's own independent distribution in time forward.
By the product formula for powers and exponentials this result extend to $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$ of any dimensions
$$\left( \partial_t-\Delta\right)\ \int_{\mathbb R^n}  \  \left( 2\pi t\right)^{-\frac{n}{2}} \ e^{-\frac{(\mathbf x-\mathbf y)^2}{2 t}} \rho_0(\mathbf y) \ d^n \mathbf y \ = \ 0$$
The bunch of problems with time direction in PDE's in mathematical physics fills racks in  libraries. For the diffusion kernel it is crucial that it makes no sense to continue  the time parameter to negative times. A negative sign of time in the PDE is a competely different theory: Positive: where the paricles will be found later, negative: where have thy possibly come from.

I like the idea of separate time evolution directions, though I can't follow this argument. Do you have a source that this is coming from? Maybe you can elaborate on some of these claims/definitions?

I added some thougts by an edit
